# $.getJSON in an event handler fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I have a page in a cordova project that's trying to send an AJAX request when the user presses the login button to authenticate the user using my REST script. The weird thing is that it works if I just put the AJAX code in the ready function but if I put it in an event handler it gets a status code of 404. Here's the code I have right now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

        <!-- Set the viewport settings to prevent scaling -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

        <!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ratchet.css">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
                $.support.cors = true;
                $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ratchet.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            app.initialize();

            function auth(username, password){
                $.getJSON("http://devserver/REST.php?callback=?", {method: "mobileAuthUser", username: username, password: password}, function(response, status, xhr){
                    alert(response);
                }).error(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert("error");
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                });
            }

            $(function(){
                auth("username", "password");
                $("#subButton").click(function(){
                    auth("username", "password");
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            /*Stops the text from being in all caps*/
            body * {
                text-transform: none;    
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="bar bar-nav">
            <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
                <button class="btn btn-positive btn-block" id="subButton">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="deviceready">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The focal piece here is

```
auth("username", "password");
$("#subButton").click(function(){
    auth("username", "password");
}
```

The `auth()` that's just run when the page is ready works just fine. The `auth()` that's run when the button is clicked will instead get an error back and in the error callback it gives me an error code of 404. What I don't understand is how I can have the exact same function call fail just because it's in an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#subButton").on('touchend', function(){
    auth("username", "password");
});
```

Instead of the `click` event.